# Best practice to handle menus in angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What is the best practice to handle showing different menus based on different contexts. For example user has not logged-in /signed-up yet will have a different menu, sign-in sign-up pages will not have any menu, logged-in user will have user's information navigation menu.

With single ng-view for an angular application what is the best way these scenarios can be handled.

Comment: What about a simple `ng-show/hide` directive within the menu itself. E.g: `ng-show="userLoggedIn()"`

Comment: Somewhat depends on level of security needed. Thus question is too broad

Comment: I prefer `ng-if`, in this case we allocate unuseful DOM.

Comment: Somehow I feel conditional code was not modular enough. @charlie if I were to use api for authentication in terms of security level, how would the routes look like. Can I manage without ng-show hide or ng-if

Comment: routes can be blocked several different ways based on auth without using `ng-if` or `ng-show`. If route and html isn't even available due to blocking security is higher. Still overly broad question and there are lots of tutorials and modules available

Comment: Great, thanks. Will look for them.